# ios Core Data Design Issue

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to create a Core Data model for my application. I have having issues in defining the attributes and relationships. Here's the scenario

I have a Contract Management Application. So the basic entity is **Contract**. It has a **Tenant** but can have multiple **Landlord**s. **Tenant** and **Landlord**s can either be a **Person** or a **Company** type.

I have defined the entities as shown in the table below.

[image]

I only created **Landlord** and **Tenant** to reference them easily from **Contract**. I feel that **Contract** should have a To-Many relationship with a name of landlords as a Contract can have multiple landlords. The problem I have is that each **Landlord** could either be a **Person** or a **Company**. Same goes with the tenant, though it would always be one for a **Contract**.

Here's the updated Snapshot of **Landlord**

[image]

& **Tenant** Entities

[image]

Can you please help me define what relations should I create from **Contract** to **Landlord** && **Tenant** ( along with reverse relations if any ) ?

Here's the ER Diagram that I could think of my head ! ;)

[image: ER Diagram]

Can you please help me define what relations should I create from **Contract** to **Landlord** && **Tenant** ( along with reverse relations if any ) with each of them being either a **Company** or a **Person** ?

Thanks

Comment: chalk out the ER diagram first

Comment: I added the ER diagram @SahebRoy. Thanks for reaching out !

Comment: I think you should define an entity, perhaps "Counterparty", and then make both Person and Company sub-entities of Counterparty.  Then in Contract both the Landlord and Tenant relationships should be linked to Counterparty.

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a few data structures similar to yours.

What works for me in this situation is to set up an Entity that defines the roles that each person plays in a contract and another Entity that defines type of role.

So in your case I'd think about using this structure...

- Delete the Entities Landlord and Tenant;
- Add a new Entity called **ContractRole** with Relationships `contract`, `company`, `person` and `contractRoleType`.
- Add a new Entity called **ContractRoleType** with Attribute `type` and Relationship `contractRole`;
- to the existing Entities **Contract**, **Company** and **Person**, add a new Relationship `contractRole`;
- the Entity **ContractRoleType** will have at least two `type`s "Landlord" and "Tenant".

So for each Contract you will enter data for at least two ContractRoles, one with ContractRoleType "Landlord" and one with ContractRoleType "Tenant".

I find this type of data structure very flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I know for a ContractRole whether it is a company or a person ? Perhaps add another attribute ?

Comment: In my answer I've suggested similar... add another relationship (not attribute)... in this case the relationship `contractRoleType` with inverse `type` in the entity **ContractRoleType**. You can then enter default types into the entity **ContractRoleType** during startup.

Comment: In reality even this suggestion of mine is not required, as which relationship is set in the Entity **ContractRole** will determine whether the "type" is a "Landlord" or "Tenant".